# Parse Rate Limit Cleaning Data

Tags: parse-platform

I have a number of rows 5K plus that I have a long and Lat column for, I'd like to add another column location and create a GeoPoint from the long and lat so I can do some GeoLocation queries with parse from an application.

I've written the following cloudCode but am hitting the rate limit as this uses > 30 requests per second. I'm quite happy to wait 1 hr for this to completre all I want to do is create the geopoints once then I'm done.

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("locationCleanUp", function(request, response) {

    var setLocation = function(longitude,latitude) {

        var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude});

        //console.log(point);

        return point;

    };

    var query = new Parse.Query("WeatherSitelistCodes");

    query.each(

        function(result) {

            //console.log(result.get('name'));
            result.set("location",setLocation(result.get("longitude"),result.get("latitude")));
            result.save();

        },{
            success: function(result) {
                response.success("All Done!");
                //console.log(result.set("location",setLocation(result.get("longitude"),result.get("latitude"))));

            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("Error: " + error);
            }
        });
     });
```

Any tips or advice on how I can do this would be greatly appreciated!

My next port of call is to clean the data locally and then upload but I've got this far...

Comment: It's a bit of a pain parse.com don't provide a tool within the management console for  fixing this, many people must have long and lat that need converting to their "GeoLocation" types.

Answer (score 2):

It kind of sucks as parse doesn't offer anything to help with this and the solution sucks for them as its a live wait loop like:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Which you would call after each save to limit the overall throughput.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  Parse.com states that cloud functions will be killed after 15 sec of wall clock time.  To my understanding, the only way to get this done is to run a scheduled job that looks for the condition that the OP wants to change and changes it in small chucks (say, 1k rows at a time).  Either that, or use this or some technique like it to throttle from the client.

Comment: @danh good point, it should indeed be run as a job, then it will have 15 minutes of runtime (jobs can be run manually as well as by schedule)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks danh and Wain.

I ended up using a background job run every 5 mins that queried the updatedAt date for records that were less than today.

```
// Use Parse.Cloud.define to define as many cloud functions as you want.
// For example:
Parse.Cloud.job("locationCleanUp", function(request, response) {

    var setLocation = function(longitude,latitude) {

        var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude:latitude, longitude:longitude});

        console.log(point);

        return point;

    };

    var date = new Date("2015-05-08");
    var site = Parse.Object.extend("WeatherSitelistCodes");
    var query = new Parse.Query("WeatherSitelistCodes");
    query.lessThan("updatedAt",date);

    query.each(

        function(result) {
            var lat = parseFloat(result.get("latitude"));
            var longi = parseFloat(result.get("longitude"));
            var newLocation = setLocation(longi,lat);
            var location = JSON.stringify(result.get("location"));

            console.log("Location: " + result.get("name"));

                result.save({
                    location: newLocation
                },{
                    success: function(result) {
                        console.log("Saved!");

                    },

                    error: function(result, error) {
                        console.log("Error" + error.message);
                    }
                });

            },{
            success: function() {
            // results is an array of Parse.Object.
            console.log('Done!');
            response.success("Updated Records!!");
              },
            error: function(error) {
            // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
            console.log('Error: +' error.message);
            response.error("Failed to save vote. Error=" + error.message);
            }
        });
});
```